# Is there a way to save a full pdb file in PYMOL after uploading biological unit?

Tags: pymol

pdb code: `2obt`

The pdb file has a coordinates of a monomer.

I have used following commands to generate an assembly, or in other words to upload one more biological unit so that the protein would be a dimer:

```
set assembly, ""
fetch 2obt, asu, async=0

set assembly, "1"
fetch 2obt, assembly1, async=0
```

After generating the functional dimer in  pymol under name `assembly1`, I have an important issue that I cannot save a dimer structure in pdb file with dimer coordinates. Does anybody has an idea how to go around it or is it even possible to do that?

Comment: can we says that "after uploading the biological unit is not the right wording" ?? --> When loading mmCIF structure files, the assembly setting controls whether PyMOL loads the asymmetric unit (assembly="") or a biological unit (e.g. assembly="1"). Assembly identifiers in mmCIF files can be arbitrary strings, but usually are numeric and most files define at least assembly "1".  I guess the biological unit is created applying same symmetry operator on the asymmetric unit (or am I wrong ??). Ok PymolWiki says loading, actually loads .....

Answer (score 4):

So on the GUI form of PyMOL on the right hand side you have a list of what is ambiguously called `objects` in PyMOL (models elsewhere), which can be enabled or disabled by clicking on their name.
The name also has a `1/1` in green or similar. This indicates the state. In your case you have 2 states.

To split a multistate object use

```
split_state prot_A
```

To combine two objects one uses the command

```
create new_name, prot_A or prot_B
```

Now, this has two caveats which if violated result in a nasty piece of modern art:

- if the chains, segment ids and residues are the same
- if you had two overlapping macromolecules

To deal with the first, change the chain id on one of them.

alter prot_B, chain='B'
   sort

Segment identifier is a weird thing that most comp-biochem tools dislike, so I like to remove that

alter prot_B, segi=''
   sort

Now when you go to save your `new_name` object, in the popup of the GUI you get a dropdown menu defaulted to enabled (visible objects that have not be clicked to be disabled). There you can choose `new_name`.

### Aligning two

If someone that is in not the OP author has a template protein and needs to make a dimer of another based on that, the process is the same.

```
create twin, prot_B
align twin, prot_A and chain B
alter twin, chain='B'
sort
```

### SDF files

If someone else has a multicompound sdf where the state is the header name, I strongly advise not to use `split_state`. Yes, the python pymol module (not the app) handles states in a really weird way, but states can be selected with `state 1` selection algebra and `state` is an argument for most commands that do not accept `state` selector.